# How to set path for local bin file in cshrc

Tags: linux, csh

I use `csh` and I have made a binary file `rlwrap` and the path is `/home/srinadel/bin/rlwrap` locally

```
[srinadel@slc ~/bin]$ ls -ltr
total 259
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 srinadel dba 221806 Oct 21 03:48 rlwrap
```

Now I want to `set the path` for it in my `~/.cshrc` file.
I have added this line in my `~/.cshrc` file.

```
setenv PATH {$PATH}:/home/srinadel/bin/rlwrap
```

and I have `added alias in my /etc/csh.cshrc file` as

```
alias sqlplus 'rlwrap sqlplus'
```

And in the new terminal,I have seen the alias where I have found `sqlplus rlwrap sqlplus`.
I have tried to run sqlplus going all the way to my folder where `rlwrap` is located and run the `sqlplus` as `rlwrap sqlplus` and it worked fine.

Now I have tried to run `sqlplus` using alias,It didn't work.It says `command:rlwrap is not found`;

Now I have to some other folder and tried to run using `rlwrap sqlplus` just to see if the alias is at faulty,Even this didn't work.The same error was thrown-`command:rlwrap is not found`.

So I think there should be a problem with the path of the rlwrap.So I have run `echo $PATH`.
The output is as follows:

```
/ade/srinadel_collation_ts/oss/utl:/ade/srinadel_collation_ts/oss/bin:/opt/microfocus/cobol/bin:/usr/local/redhat/packages/perl_5.6.1/bin:/ade/srinadel_collation_ts/plsql/bin:/   ade/srinadel_collation_ts/plsql/utl:/ade/srinadel_collation_ts/plsql/utl/scripts:.:/ade/srinadel_collation_ts/buildtools/bin:/ade/b/2332830812/oracle/bin:/ade/b/2332830812/oracle/rdbms/utl:/ade/b/2332830812/oracle/rdbms/utl:/ade/srinadel_collation_ts/utl:/ade/srinadel_collation_ts/nlsrtl3/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/dev_infra/platform/bin:/usr/dev_infra/      generic/bin:/usr/local/bin:/etc:/usr/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/local/nde/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/ade/bin:/ade/srinadel_collation_ts/odbctests/odbc_ptest/bin:/ade/      srinadel_collation_ts/rdbms_topaz:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/dev_infra/platform/bin:/usr/dev_infra/generic/bin:/usr/local/bin:/ usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/ade/bin:/home/srinadel/bin/rlwrap:/home/srinadel/bin/rlwrap:/ade/srinadel_collation_ts/utl:/ade/srinadel_collation_ts/reliaty/utl:/ade/srinadel_collation_ts/ant/bin:/home/srinadel/bin/rlwrap
```

Where the path to the `tlwrap` is shown correctly.

What might be the problem..Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PATH` variable is a list of **directories** to be searched, you need

```
setenv PATH {$PATH}:/home/srinadel/bin
```

IHTH